# How do I statically provision a volume for a StatefulSet?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using Google Kubernetes Engine and would like my `StatefulSet` to use my previously created disk `my-app-disk` instead of dynamically creating new persistent disk for each replica in the set. My config is as follows:

`PersistentVolume` yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-app-data
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 60Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: my-app-disk
    fsType: ext4
```

`PersistentVolumeClaim` yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-app-data
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 60Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
```

`StatefulSet` yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: my-stateful-set
spec:
  serviceName: my-stateful-set
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: gcr.io/projectname/my-app:0.0.3
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
        volumeMounts:
        - name: my-app-data
          mountPath: /data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: my-app-data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 50Gi
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`StatefulSet` will create it's own `PersistentVolumeClaim` for each pod so you don't have to create one yourself. A `PersistentVolume` and a `PersistentVolumeClaim` will bind exclusively [one to one](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#binding). Your PVC is binding to your volume so any PVCs created by the `StatefulSet` can't bind to your volume so it won't be used.

In your case your `PersistentVolume` and the `StatefulSet` below should do the trick. Make sure to delete the `PersistentVolumeClaim` you created so that it's not bound to your `PersistentVolume`. Also, make sure the storage class name is set properly below on your PV and in `volumeClaimTemplates` on your `StatefulSet` below or the PVC made by the `StatefulSet` may not bind to your volume.

`PersistentVolume.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-app-data
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 60Gi
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: my-app-disk
    fsType: ext4
```

`StatefulSet.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: my-stateful-set
spec:
  serviceName: my-stateful-set
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: gcr.io/projectname/my-app:0.0.3
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
        volumeMounts:
        - name: my-app-data
          mountPath: /data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: my-app-data
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: my-app
      storageClassName: standard
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 50Gi
```

Comment: How this would look for 3 replicas and 3 disks? my-app-disk1, my-app-disk2, my-app-disk3?

Comment: The StatefulSet would just have 3 replicas and you would have 3 PersistentVolumes with the app=myapp label since that's what's used for the PersistentVolumeClaim label selector.

Comment: This does not work on AWS. 
```
Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "gp2-encrypted": claim.Spec.Selector is not supported for dynamic provisioning on AWS
```

Comment: This is completely correct. After hours of going through the Kubernetes documents I found absolutely nothing stating this is possible. Much appreciated.